# warning LGHT1076: ICE71: The Media table has no entries

Tags: wix3

Installer created in wix3 setup project fails to install with windows application log message "installation success or error status: 1603". Also seeing "warning LGHT1076: ICE71: The Media table has no entries." when building the msi. Below is the Product.wxs file. Wix NOOB any help greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?define Test_TargetDir=$(var.Test.TargetDir)?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="Test_1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="NP" UpgradeCode="8ad05ea9-ba50-49ab-8c78-ff2d5df80760">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Test_1" />
                <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>

        <Icon Id="MyIcon" SourceFile="Icons\Test.ico" />
        <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
            <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="afe4401f-1d30-49d8-8d3d-6b2a8baea90c">
                <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Name="Test_1" Description="Test_1" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]Test.exe" Icon="MyIcon" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            <!-- </Component> -->
            <Component Id="FTDI2XX.xml" Guid="5a160538-7074-491c-b0d4-8bd607bf532d">
              <File Id="FTDI2XX.xml" Name="FTDI2XX.xml" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)FTDI2XX.xml" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="NationalInstruments.Common.dll" Guid="04196434-4b7f-464e-ad36-ad7a37626646">
              <File Id="NationalInstruments.Common.dll" Name="NationalInstruments.Common.dll" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)NationalInstruments.Common.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" Guid="a04403e5-5a18-4d77-9683-f28bd40f78d5">
              <File Id="NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" Name="NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.exe" Guid="0fb6652c-15aa-49ad-a767-782789e09bfe">
              <File Id="Test.exe" Name="Test.exe" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.exe" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.exe.config" Guid="35269577-ee7f-4ead-94ed-be04d30d8db4">
              <File Id="Test.exe.config" Name="Test.exe.config" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.exe.config" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="FTDI2XX.dll" Guid="3406afc4-7e7d-456e-aa07-c40a13f13fb7">
              <File Id="FTDI2XX.dll" Name="FTDI2XX.dll" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)FTDI2XX.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.pdb" Guid="787670e1-4161-4388-b936-49f03b136ab2">
              <File Id="Test.pdb" Name="Test.pdb" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.pdb" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.ico" Guid="1fea4f4e-0de5-4bdf-b4f0-9ec2a68fbd16">
              <File Id="Test.ico" Name="Test.ico" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.ico" />
            </Component>

        </ComponentGroup>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Test_1" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />
        </Feature>

    </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself. The location of the Feature element was wrong also added the registry entry. New Product.wxs file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?define Test_TargetDir=$(var.Test.TargetDir)?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="Test_1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="NP" UpgradeCode="8ad05ea9-ba50-49ab-8c78-ff2d5df80760">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Test_1" Level="1">

            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />

        </Feature>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Test_1" />
                <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Icon Id="MyIcon" SourceFile="Icons\Test.ico" />

        <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
            <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="*">
                <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Name="Test_1" Description="Test_1" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]Test.exe" Icon="MyIcon" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
                <RegistryValue
                        Root="HKCU"
                        Key="Software\NP\Test_1"
                        Name="installed"
                        Type="integer"
                        Value="1"
                        KeyPath="yes"/>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>

    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>

        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            <!-- </Component> -->
            <Component Id="FTDI2XX.xml" Guid="5a160538-7074-491c-b0d4-8bd607bf532d">
                <File Id="FTDI2XX.xml" Name="FTDI2XX.xml" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)FTDI2XX.xml" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="NationalInstruments.Common.dll" Guid="04196434-4b7f-464e-ad36-ad7a37626646">
                <File Id="NationalInstruments.Common.dll" Name="NationalInstruments.Common.dll" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)NationalInstruments.Common.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" Guid="a04403e5-5a18-4d77-9683-f28bd40f78d5">
                <File Id="NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" Name="NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.exe" Guid="0fb6652c-15aa-49ad-a767-782789e09bfe">
                <File Id="Test.exe" Name="Test.exe" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.exe" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.exe.config" Guid="35269577-ee7f-4ead-94ed-be04d30d8db4">
                <File Id="Test.exe.config" Name="Test.exe.config" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.exe.config" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="FTDI2XX.dll" Guid="3406afc4-7e7d-456e-aa07-c40a13f13fb7">
                <File Id="FTDI2XX.dll" Name="FTDI2XX.dll" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)FTDI2XX.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.pdb" Guid="787670e1-4161-4388-b936-49f03b136ab2">
                <File Id="Test.pdb" Name="Test.pdb" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.pdb" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Test.ico" Guid="1fea4f4e-0de5-4bdf-b4f0-9ec2a68fbd16">
                <File Id="Test.ico" Name="Test.ico" Source="$(var.Test_TargetDir)Test.ico" />
            </Component>

        </ComponentGroup>

    </Fragment>

</Wix>
```